# Copy and paste problem of JetBrains Projector terminal

Tags: terminal, copy, paste, jetbrains-ide, projector

When I use <kbd>Command + C</kbd> / <kbd>V</kbd> to copy and paste on the Projector terminal, there is always leading `c` and tailing `v`.

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

[image]